# Enter key behavior changed when pasting

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When pasting in Excel using the enter key, the selected region should be released. This was working fine until now, but suddenly pasting using the enter key has the same behavior as a regular paste using ctrl + v. (It does not release the selection anymore.)

How can I fix this? Many thanks.

**update:**
Upon further inspection it seems that one of my macro's is interfering with my enter key's behavior. It's a simple macro with shortcut Ctrl + Shift + Y that highlights the selected region yellow. How come this shortcut/macro interferes with my enter key's behavior and how can I fix this?

```
Sub MAKEYELLOW()
'
' MAKEYELLOW Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Y
'
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Opening the workbook without importing/recording this macro will make the enter paste key behave like it should.

Comment: Do you have any Add-ons installed? These can interfere with the clipboard interactions. Try disabling all Add-ons (start Excel in safe mode) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Raystafarian You select the area you want to copy, press ctrl + c, then go to the target area and press enter. Just like you would with ctrl + v.

Comment: With what OS does that functionality work?

Comment: @Raystafarian Windows.. and I'll try that Vicky.

Comment: Does using windows key + enter work?

Comment: @Vicky It seems I don't have any add-ons installed, so that can't be it. I've updated my question. windows key + enter doesn't solve it either

Comment: Doesn't make any difference for me if I create that macro and assign that key combination to it - enter still works to paste. Can you update your question with the text of your macro (Developer->Macros->Edit)?

Comment: @Vicky just to be sure, pasting itself does work, but it does not release the selection anymore as stated [here](http://www.worldstart.com/paste-with-enter-key-excel/)

Comment: Yes, sorry. It works fine here - pastes and releases the selection. Whether or not I use the Ctrl-Shift-Y macro on the selection or another area first or not. And that macro is identical to the one I created myself in terms of the code.

Comment: Can you post / share somewhere (dropbox?) a spreadsheet with this macro that gives you this issue?

Comment: @Vicky Since it's IP sensitive information from my company, I'll post it later today without any data, when I have access to i.e. dropbox. Thanks for the help in advance